# Adding an image to a div section in css

Tags: html, css

```
<div id="nav_banner">
<br>
<a class="smoothScroll" href="#home">Home</a>
<a class="smoothScroll" href="#contactme">Email</a>
<br>
<div id="nav_banner2">
<a class="smoothScroll" href="https://twitter.com" target="_blank" title="Twitter">Twitter</a>
<a class="smoothScroll" href="https://facebook.com" target="_blank" title="fb">facebook</a>
</div>
</div>
```

I am trying to add a background image inside the nav_bannner section of the html page..

here is my css code to do that:

```
#nav_banner
{

    width:100%;
    position:fixed;
    bottom:0px;
    background:white;
    left:0px;
    right:0px;
    height:100px;
    padding-top:5px;
    padding-bottom:5px;
    padding-left:5px;
    padding-right:5px;
    font-size:30px;
    word-spacing: 50px;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: Copperplate,Copperplate Gothic Light,fantasy; 
    background-image:url('images/shsf.png');

}
```

But when i load the page.. the image is not showing up... the nav banner simply has white background.

Can anyone tell me what is the issue with the code above?

Comment: Is the path to the image correct? Using a valid path works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/s4b4zk7n/

Comment: yes.  the image is located inside images folder.

Comment: check the spelling of the image file name as well - I just tried this with my own random image and it worked just fine.

Comment: thats weird.. i dont understand.. should i try using the full path?

Comment: Change background to background-color

Comment: could it be that the image is too big?....

Comment: when i try to add the link @j08691 used , its working fine.. but when i go back to my image.. it shows the white background again...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, check the path. The code works well for `Chromium (Version 39.0.2171.65 Ubuntu 14.04)`.

Second, if you have a small image you can embed it directly to css by **data-uri** https://css-tricks.com/data-uris/